# I am facing as issue while using websocket with flask. Not able to publish the response to UI

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, websocket

I tried to send update from server(postgresql database) to client whenever there is a change in database. But using socketio.emit the data is not reaching the client.
Note: Added trigger functions to the database table

`

```
Code 
`
from flask import Flask, request
from flask import render_template
from flask_cors import cross_origin
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_restful.utils import cors
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import eventlet
from flask_cors import CORS
import psycopg2
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
CORS(app,resources={r"/*":{"origins":"*"}})
socketio = SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins="*")

# Connect to the PostgreSQL database
conn = psycopg2.connect(
        database=database_name,
        user=database_user_name,
        password=database_password,
        host=database_host,
        port=database_port
    )
cursor = conn.cursor()
# Listen for changes in the database
cursor.execute("LISTEN master_updates")
cursor.execute("LISTEN agent_table_updates")
conn.commit()

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template("client.html")

# Send updates to clients via WebSocket

@socketio.on("update")
@app.route("/handle_update")
@cross_origin()
def handle_update():
    print('Client connected')
    if True:
        conn.poll()
        while conn.notifies:
            notify = conn.notifies.pop(0)
            print('database_change', notify.payload)
            payload = {
                "message": "DB_updated",
                "data": notify.payload
            }
            json_object = json.dumps(payload, indent = 4)
            socketio.emit('update', json_object)
            return json_object

        else:
            payload = {"message": "no updates"}
            socketio.emit("update", payload)
            return payload
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host=API_host_ip, debug=True, port=API_host_port)`
```

I am expecting the websocket to publish the response. no console error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.